# Using while or if as a condition for recursion leads to different results

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion, while-loop

This is a simple recursive function that should run 10 times, the condition is if.

```
count = 0  
def recurse(count):
    *if* count < 10:
        print count
        count += 1
        recurse(count)

recurse(count)
```

Output

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` OK

When I use a while loop, the results are wildly different and I don't understand why it does not output 0 to 9.

Code

```
count = 0
def recurse(count):
    *while* count < 10:
        print count
        count += 1
        recurse(count)

recurse(count)
```

Output

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 9 9 7 8 9 9 8 9 9 6 7 8 9 9 8 9 9 7..... 8 9 9`

You can try it here https://repl.it/nHa/3, I don't know how to create a link with the code though.

anyone see what I am doing wrong.

Edit.

Output of code 2 is finite.

Example using 3 as a limit.

- using if `0 1 2`  https://repl.it/nHa/3
- using while `0 1 2 2 1 2 2`  https://repl.it/nHa/2

Comment: Simply because you are doing recursion..........

Comment: Start with `count = 7` or decrease the limit to `while count < 3:` – it would be easier to understand the pattern in a shorter output ;) You might also try to `print "("` before the recursive `recurse(count)` and `print ")"` after it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to  *return recurse* in the if block:

```
count = 0
def recurse(count):
    if count < 10:
        print(count)
        return recurse(count+1)

In [63]: recurse(0)
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

And do the same in the while block:

```
def recurse(count):
    while count < 10:
        print(count)
        count += 1
        return recurse(count)
```

A graph showing the recursive calls and the order may help:

[image: recursive calls]

We start at 0 then recurse on 1, 2 and finally 3, then we move to 2 recurse again to 3 and finally we reach the last number 3 and the function ends.

Now what happens when you *return*:

[image]

What the colour and numbering means:

> Note: 1. The edges are numbered by the order in which they were traversed by the execution. 2. The edges are colored from black to grey to indicate order of traversal: black edges first, grey edges last.

The graph was generated using [rcviz](https://github.com/carlsborg/rcviz)

Comment: Its not infinite, its breaking. If I use 3 as a limit, the output is 0 1 2 2 1 2 2, the execution path which the code uses to output these data, is what is confusing me

Comment: WoW ... GRRRAAAAAPPPHHS!

Comment: @BhargavRao, a picture paints a thousand words!

Comment: @briankip, lol,  it is not totally obvious what is happening by just seeing the output,  hopefully the graph helps. if you want to play around with more input you can install rcviz with pip and the instructions on how to use it are in the link. It is basically just adding a decorator, calling the function and then calling a method passing the name you want to store the graph under.

Comment: How come, without the `return` statement, we get the desired output with the recursion inside an `if` statement but not inside the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `count` is local to each of the function that you are calling! Hence each time you have a *recursive* function call you will *iterate* the loop again! Thus your *base-case* is never satisfied. Use `return` and you will get your desired output. This is because you will then save the state of the variable `count`. (The other way is to make count a global variable, which is a bad way to go)

```
count = 0
def recurse(count):
    while count < 10:
        print count
        count += 1
        count = recurse(count)
    return count

recurse(count)
```

In this you are re-assigning the count value back to your variable in the outer recursive functions, hence your base case will be satisfied.

Comment: The loop ends, so the base case is satisfied at some time, I just don't understand why its satisfied.

Comment: Huh? Can you please elaborate? Base cases are for recursive functions. In your flawed program with while it ends only when the local variable count on your first function call reaches the loop termination condition in this case count < 10. That is all the mistake in your program

Comment: @briankip Yes, your program will end after printing 1024 characters! To visualize that draw a recursive tree

Comment: When  I use 3 as a limit and I output `count` before the while, count is 3 but the check ignores that, and prints 2 as count, and continues. See the code here https://repl.it/nHa

Comment: @briankip Aha! You are now getting the point! Nice. See that is the difference between `while` and `if`. The output is 3 outside the loop. The output you are seeing after the `Count is 3` line is from a different recursive call and not from the same! As predicted you will get 2^(3)-1 outputs because of that recursion. Like wise for 10 elements you will get 2 ^ (10) -1 that is 1023 outputs! This is all what I can say for now. Do construct a recursive tree and trace line by line, you will certainly understand what I am saying. All the best. Ty :)

Answer (score 1):

You call `recurse(0)`, which counts from 0 to 9. It *also* calls `recurse(1)`, `recurse(2)`, ..., `recurse(10)`. Each of which in turn prints numbers and causes more `recurse(...)` calls, each again printing numbers and causing further calls. And so on. Of course this explodes.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating *and* recursing, as if you'd have used a *for* instead of *if* in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

One often has a choice between iteration and recursion. In the `while` loop case you are trying to do both at the same time. `If` is the proper choice to test conditions for terminating recursion.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong depends on what you want to achieve... But whatever you want, I do not believe 
the code

```
def recurse(count):
    if count < 10:
        print count
        count += 1
        recurse(count)
```

gave you the output

```
0..9
```

Comment: That code does print 0 thru 9 when called by `recurse(0`).

Comment: Ouput `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` is quite different from `0..9`, isn't it? The latter is just 4 characters long while the former consists of about 19 characters.

Comment: I think most people would read `0..9` in this context and know that it is shorthand for 0 thru 9 each on its own line.

Comment: I meant 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9